# get next item on the list which isn't rated

Tags: c#, .net

I have that class:

```
public class PhotoRate
{
    public int PhotoRateId { get; set; } // in database this is primary key, autoincrement
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }
    public int? Rate { get; set; }
}
```

And list of objects that class:

```
private static List<PhotoRate> photoRates = new List<PhotoRate>
{
    new PhotoRate
    {
        PhotoRateId = 5,
        PhotoId = 124,
        Rate = 3
    },
    new PhotoRate
    {
        PhotoRateId = 7,
        PhotoId = 124,
        Rate = null
    },
    new PhotoRate
    {
        PhotoRateId = 16,
        PhotoId = 126,
        Rate = 5
    },
    new PhotoRate
    {
        PhotoRateId = 23,
        PhotoId = 127,
        Rate = null
    }
};
```

**I want something like that:** I give `PhotoRateId` and gets next `PhotoRateId` of `PhotoRate` which isn't rated (Rate is null) or null if all `PhotoRate` objects are rated.

I have that algorithm but maybe you can tell me better solution?

```
private static int? GetNextPhotoRateId(int photoRateId)
{
    PhotoRate currentPhotoRate = photoRates.First(x => x.PhotoRateId == photoRateId);

    if (photoRates.Count(x => x.Rate == null) == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    List<PhotoRate> notRatedPhotoRatesAfterCurrentPhotoRate = photoRates.Where(x => x.PhotoRateId > currentPhotoRate.PhotoRateId && x.Rate == null).ToList();
    if (notRatedPhotoRatesAfterCurrentPhotoRate.Count > 0)
    {
        return notRatedPhotoRatesAfterCurrentPhotoRate.First().PhotoRateId;
    }

    return photoRates.First(x => x.Rate == null).PhotoRateId;
}
```

Comment: So you want the first unrated item that occurs after `photoRateId`?

Comment: your algorithm assumes that the entries will be sorted by `photoRateId`. Is this always the case?

Comment: Did you encounter any performance issue? Do you have any test case to measure?

Comment: @simonalexander2005 - yes, always sorted by photoRateId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make your algorithm much easier, as follows:

```
private static int? GetNextPhotoRateId(int photoRateId)
{
    var result = photoRates
        // We check if there are Ids bigger than the one received as parameter
        // in this case we just take the records having PhotoRateId bigger than the id received as parameter
        .Where(pr => photoRates.Any(p => p.PhotoRateId > photoRateId) ? pr.PhotoRateId > photoRateId: true)
        // And with Rate null
        .Where(pr => pr.Rate == null)
        // Select just the PhotoRateId
        .Select(pr => pr.PhotoRateId)
        // Order the result by Id
        .OrderBy(pr => pr)
        // Then take the first (the next one after the Id passed as parameter) 
        // or the default value (0)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    // If the result was 0, then return null
    if (result == 0) return null;
    // Otherwise return the result
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Second `Where` may fail if no collection for `PhotoRateId > photoRateId` generated by first `Where`. Is it?

Comment: @Irshad no, Linq is smart enough to take care of the situation without throwing an exception

Comment: @user449689 but now if you give PhotoRateId last object on the list then it will return null and in that case it should seek from the begining.

Comment: @user3691221 based on what you said, I edited my answer. Have a look.

Comment: @user449689 - thx - it is almost what I need (one small mistake - in Any clause it should be also .Where(pr => pr.Rate == null) )

Answer (score 0):

How about this;

```
        private int? GetNextPhotoRateId(int photoRateId)
        {
            //Check all photoRates have rated
            if (photoRates.Count(x => x.Rate == null).Equals(0))
                return null;

            //Get next photorateid of non rated photorate
            PhotoRate photoRate = photoRates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PhotoRateId > photoRateId && x.Rate == null);

            return photoRate == null ?
                photoRateId ://no higher id
                photoRate.PhotoRateId;
        }
```

EDIT: Use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First` because `FirstOrDefault` Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no element is found. Throws exception only if the source is null. Use `First` when you know or expect the sequence to have at least one element. (In your case `FirstOrDefault` is appropriate because the condition you're expecting not always gonna happen.). And no need to call `Where` and `Count` you can do it with one `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in one line:

```
// assuming you haven't overwritten default(PhotoRate). If the list is guaranteed to be in order, the OrderBy can be removed. Uses C# 6
private static int? GetNextPhotoRateId(int photoRateId)
{
    return photoRates.Where(p=>p.Rate == null && p.PhotoRateId >photoRateId).OrderBy(p=>p.PhotoRateId).FirstOrDefault()?.PhotoRateId;
}
```

Comment: no because if you give PhotoRateId last object on the list then it will return null and in that case it should seek from the begining

Comment: Can you please explain me what is the meaning of this notation FirstOrDefault()? I don't know that the question mark stands for. Thanks.

Comment: "?." is the null-propagating operator, and is new to C# 6 (you don't specify a version in your question). It means "if anything before this is null, return null, otherwise return the next bit"

Comment: @simonalexander2005 I'm not the guy that asked the question ;) anyway thanks a lot for the explanation

Comment: ah yes, sorry :) no problem. see this (http://davefancher.com/2014/08/14/c-6-0-null-propagation-operator/) for example, for more info